# How to keep selection when clicking other item (jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've got some text selected on page. When I use this it will not get de-selected when I click `.container`:

```
jQuery('.container').on("mousedown", function(){
    jQuery('.block').addClass('myclass');
});
```

But when I use this, the text will get de-selected:

```
jQuery('.container').on("click", function(){
    jQuery('.block').addClass('myclass');
});
```

The problem with first one is that it will remove `.myclass` as soon as I release mouse button. Is there a way to save my selection somehow while I click `.container`?

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this:

```
jQuery('.container').on("click", function(ev){
    jQuery('.block').addClass('myclass');
    ev.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but text still gets de-selected. If there is no way to prevent that I can always save current selection and restore but I would prefer not doing this.

Comment: My mistake - it works with `mousedown` - it won't remove class. Something else was doing this in my case.